# Change matrix elements based on their neighbors

Tags: arrays, matrix, matlab

I need to write a script to change my matrix A (1x25) into B (1x24)

```
A = [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1];
```

I would like to change this matrix by this rule:

- I want to replace all the elements selected two by two as long as they are neighbors When there are two consecutive 1 (1 and 1), replace them by 1.
- When there are two consecutive 0, replace them by -1
- When there is 1 followed by 0, replace them by i.
- When there is 0 followed by 1, replace them by -i.

Finally I need to have this Matrix B (1x24)

```
B = [1 1 1 i -1 -i 1 1 1 i -1 -i 1 1 1 i -1 -i i -i 1 1 1 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1];
for Index=1:length(A)-1
   Temp=A(Index)+A(Index+1);
   switch(Temp)
       case 0, B(Index)=-1;
       case 1, if(A(Index)==1) B(Index)=i; else B(Index)=-i; end;
       case 2, B(Index)=1;
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
dA = diff(A);
B = i*(dA==-1) + A(2:end).*~dA + -1*(~A(2:end).*~dA) + -i*(dA==1)
```

**Sample output with i = 5**

```
B = 
 1 1 1 5 -1 -5 1 1 1 5 -1 -5 1 1 1 -1 -5 5 -5 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]; %// data
values = [-1 -i i 1]; %// values for 00, 01 10, 11 in that order

B = values(2*A(1:end-1)+A(2:end)+1);
```